# Tail sum for expectation

Tags: probability, integration

In [Pitman's Probability](http://books.google.com/books?id=L6IWgaCuilwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Pitman%27s%20Probability&hl=en&ei=s1RtTqncHabc0QGKi6XXBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tail%20sum&f=false), the tail sum formula for expectation is introduced for a nonnegative (0,1,...) discrete random variable $X$:

$$E(X) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X > i).$$

1. I wonder if there is a similar formula for nonnegative continuous
   random variable $X$:

   $$E(X) = \int_0^\infty P(X > x) dx?$$

   If no, are there some conditions for it to hold? And how can it be
   proved?

   Here is my thought:

   If the cdf $F$ of $X$ is bijective, then $X=F^{-1}(U)$ for some
   random variable $U$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$. So $$E(X) =
       \int_0^1 F^{-1}(u) du.$$

   To prove the tail sum formula, it suffices to prove $$\int_0^1
       F^{-1}(u) du = \int_0^\infty P(X > x) dx.$$ But I am stuck here.

   What's more, is the condition that the cdf $F$ of $X$ is bijective
   really necessary for tail sum formula to hold?
2. Can tail sum formula be generalized to a random variable that is not
   necessarily nonnegative?

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen it written as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_0^\infty x\;dF(x)$, where $F(x) = \Pr(X \le x)$ is the cumulative distribution function.  This works regardless of whether you have a continuous distribution, a discrete distribution, a singular distribution (which is neither continuous nor discrete nor a mixture of the two), or a mixture of any or all of the three kinds.  Only for continuous distributions is this the same as $\int_0^\infty x f(x)\;dx$, where $f(x)=F'(x)$ is the probability density function.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! The tail sum formula is another way to computer expectation defined as in your comment.

Comment: Similar question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/does-a-univariate-random-variables-mean-always-equal-the-integral-of-its-quanti/

Comment: In case others stumble upon this question and are also using Pitman's textbook: the continuous case is covered in Exercise 9 of Section 4.5.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172841/321264

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Fubini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem) for nonnegative functions/sums. If $x$ is a nonnegative integer,

> $$
> x=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}[x\gt i].
> $$

Likewise, if $x$ is a nonnegative real number,

> $$
> x=\int_{0}^{+\infty}[x\gt t]\mathrm dt,\qquad x=\int_{0}^{+\infty}[x\geqslant t]\mathrm dt.
> $$

Then one integrates both sides of the relevant identity with respect to the distribution $\mathrm P_X$ of $X$ and one uses Fubini theorem to change the order of the summation/integral and of the expectation.

For example, the second identity yields
$$
\mathbb E(X)=\int_\Omega X\ \mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_\Omega \int_{0}^{+\infty}[X\gt t]\mathrm dt\ \mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_\Omega [X\gt t]\mathrm d\mathbb P\ \mathrm dt
$$ that is,

> $$\mathbb E(X)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbb P(X\gt t)\ \mathrm dt.
> $$

Likewise, the first identity yields
$$
\mathbb E(X)=\int_\Omega X\ \mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_\Omega\ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}[X\gt i]\ \mathrm d\mathbb P=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\ \int_\Omega[X\gt i]\ \mathrm d\mathbb P
$$ that is,

> $$\mathbb E(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\mathbb P(X\gt i).
> $$

Comment: What does the notation dP mean? I am not familiar with this definition of expectation.

Comment: @MongH.Ng Really? This is rather surprising. How do you define the expectation of a random variable then?

Comment: In my entire college career, I have only ever see E[X} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx. I am guessing they are equivalent, but I am not sure how to parse this.

Comment: @MongH.Ng Well, so you cannot compute $E(X)$ when $X$ has no PDF? Anyway, start from your formula, note that $f(x)=-\frac d{dx}P(X\geqslant x)$ and $1=\frac d{dx}x$ hence, by an integration by parts, $$\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx=\left[-xP(X\geqslant x)\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty1\cdot(-P(X\geqslant x))dx$$ hence you are done.

Comment: @MongH.Ng https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value

Answer (score 10):

This is [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts). Take $X\geq 0$, and call its distribution function $F$. Let $g$ be an increasing differentiable function with $g(0)=0$.

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[g(X)]&=\int_0^\infty g(t) dF(t) \\
              &= \int_0^\infty -g(t) d(1-F(t)) \\
&= [-g(t)(1-F(t))]^\infty_0 - \int_0^\infty 1-F(t)d(-g(t)) \\
&= \int_0^\infty g'(t)\mathbb{P}[X>t]dt
\end{align*}$$

This reduces to what you want when $g(X)=X$.

One way we could compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ for general $X$ would be to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^+]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^-]$ in this way and then take the difference, where $X^+=\max(X,0)$ and $X^-=\max(-X,0)$.

**Justification of integration by parts:** The integration by parts works when $g(X)$ is integrable, since, by dominated convergence,
$$\begin{align}
\limsup_x g(x)\mathbb{P}[X>x] &\le \limsup_x\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}(X>x)]\\
                              &= \mathbb{E}[\limsup_x g(X)\mathbf{1}(X>x)]\\
                              &= 0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is $g(+\infty)(1-F(+\infty))=0$? Ok, $1-F(+\infty)=0$ but what if $g(t)\to +\infty$? Does $g$ have to be bounded? Or does $1-F(t)$ converge so fast to $0$, that this works for any $g$? Thanks.

Comment: @Stef I've edited the answer in response to your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, of course, if $g$ is integrable this works fine.

Answer (score 4):

First we prove that for $X \geq 0$
$$EX= \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X > t)dt.$$
We apply Fubini's theorem. Our product measure will be a product of the distribution of $X$ and Lebesgue measure. 
So $$\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>t)dt = \int_0^{\infty}\left( \int_{t}^{\infty} \nu_X(ds)\right)dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}\textbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)\textbf{1}_{(t,\infty)}(s)\nu_X(ds)\right)dt=$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_0^s dt \right) \nu_X(ds)= \int_{0}^{\infty}s \nu_X(ds)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}s\nu_X(ds)=EX$$

But, you want to have $EX=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X \geq t)dt.$

Applying what we have already proved, it is enough to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X=t)dt=0$.

Comment: We can also show that for $X \geq 0$ and for an increasing differentiable function $g$, such that $g(0)=0$ we have $$E(g(X))= \int_{0}^{\infty} g^{\prime}(t) P(X>t) dt.$$

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry about $EX=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X \geq t)dt$. I misunderstood Pitman's book for the discrete case.

Comment: No problem, but $EX= \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X \geq t)dt$. I proved the main part for this, to get $\geq$ instead of $>$ it is sufficient to show that $\int_0^{\infty}P(X=t)dt=0$ which is obvious.

Comment: Edvin: This **is** obvious when using the right approach but maybe not so obvious to every MSE reader, hence I wonder why you skip the proof of this part...

Answer (score 3):

@Did gave a great answer, and while I'm thinking about it I want to record a similar answer using slightly different notation in the case where the cumulative density function $F$ is differentiable.

In this case,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(X) &= \int_0^\infty x F'(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty [x \geq t] \, dt \,F'(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty [x \geq t] F'(x) \, dt \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty [x \geq t] F'(x) \, dx \, dt \quad \text{(Fubini's theorem)}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty F'(x) \, dx \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty 1 - F(t) \, dt.
\end{align}

(The quantity $[x \geq t]$ is equal to $1$ if $x \geq t$ and $0$ otherwise.)