# Relation between integral by parts and Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, integration

In probability, I have seen some examples for which both Fubini's theorem and integration by parts (for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals with cdf as integrator) provide different but correct solutions. For example

1. In [proving $E(|X|)=\int_0^\infty P(|X| > t)dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63756/tail-sum-for-expectation/85572#85572), Edvin and Did used Fubini's theorem, while
   Ben used integration by parts;
2. In [proving $\operatorname{median}(X)$ solves $\min_{c \in \mathbb{R}} E |X-c|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/why-does-the-median-minimize-ex-c), Did used Fubini's theorem, while Sivaram
   used integration by parts in Edit.

So I wonder if the two are related somehow? 
For example, in some cases (especially the two examples above), can one lead to the other?

1. A wide guess for going from Fubini's theorem to integration by parts is:

   Integration by parts says

   $$
       \begin{align} f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) & =  \int_a^b  g(x) \, df(x) + \int_a^b f(x) \, dg(x). \end{align}  $$

   If there is some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(c)=0$, then $$
   \int_a^b g(x) \, df(x) = \int_a^b \int_c^x dg(t)  \, df(x ) $$ If
   Fubini's theorem or some of its variants can apply, then for some $d
   \in \mathbb{R}$, $$ \int_a^b \int_c^x dg(t)  \, df(x ) = \int_c^b
   \int_d^t df(x)  \, dg(t )  = \int_c^b \int_d^x df(t)  \, dg(x )  $$
   one step closer to $\int_a^b f(x) \, dg(x)$, but still far away from
   integration by parts.
2. No idea yet about going from integration by parts to Fubini's
   theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Fubini implies integration by parts*. To see this in dimension $1$, consider  some $C^1$ functions $f$ and $g$ and the integral
$$
I=\int\limits_a^bf'(x)g(x)\mathrm dx.
$$ 
Then, the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) shows that, for every $x$, 
$$
g(x)=g(a)+\int\limits_a^xg'(t)\mathrm dt,
$$ 
hence $I=J+K$ with
$$
J=g(a)\int\limits_a^bf'(x)\mathrm dx=g(a)(f(b)-f(a)),
$$
and, using [Fubini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to justify the second equality sign below,
$$
K=\int\limits_a^bf'(x)\int\limits_a^xg'(t)\mathrm dt\mathrm dx=\int\limits_a^bg'(t)\int\limits_t^bf'(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dt=\int\limits_a^bg'(t)(f(b)-f(t))\mathrm dt.
$$
One sees that $K=L-M$ with
$$
L=f(b)\int\limits_a^bg'(t)\mathrm dt=f(b)(g(b)-g(a)),\qquad
M=\int\limits_a^bg'(t)f(t)\mathrm dt.
$$
Finally, $I=(J+L)-M$ with 
$$
J+L=g(a)(f(b)-f(a))+f(b)(g(b)-g(a))=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and spending time with me!