# Expectation of Minimum of $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, order-statistics

$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables. Let $Y = \min(X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n)$. Then, what's the expectation of $Y$(i.e., $E(Y)$)?

I have conducted some simulations by Matlab, and the results show that $E(Y)$ may equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Can anyone give a rigorous proof or some hints? Thanks!

Comment: This is known as the $Beta(1,n+1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To calculate the expected value, we're going to need the density function for $Y$. To get that, we're going to need the distribution function for $Y$. Let's start there.

By definition, $F(y) = P(Y \leq y) = 1 - P(Y > y) = 1 - P(\text{min}(X_1, \ldots, X_n) > y)$. Of course, $\text{min}(X_1, \ldots X_n) > y$ exactly when $X_i > y$ for all $i$. Since these variables are i.i.d., we have $F(y) = 1 - P(X_1 > y)P(X_2>y)\ldots P(X_n>y) = 1 - P(X_1 > y)^n$. Assuming the $X_i$ are uniformly distributed on $(a, b)$, this yields
$$F(y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       1 - \left(\frac{b-y}{b-a}\right)^n & : y \in (a, b)\\
       0 & : y < a\\
       1 & : y > b
     \end{array}
\right.$$
We take the derivative to get the density function.
$$f(y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       \frac{n}{b-a} \left(\frac{b-y}{b-a}\right)^{n-1} & : y \in (a, b)\\
       0 & : \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
\right.$$
Now $E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f(y) dy$. The integral is straightforward; I'll leave the details to you. I calculate $E(Y) = \frac{b+na}{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You extend it to a more general setting, which is very helpful.

Comment: There's no sense in taking the derivative and then integrating; you can just use the [tail-sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63756/3157) to calculate the expectation directly from the integral.

Answer (score 30):

Yes.  Assuming a $U(0,1)$, note that

$$\Pr\Bigl(\min_i X_i\leq x\Bigr) = 
 1- \Pr\Bigl(\min_i X_i\geq x\Bigr) = 
1- (1-x)^n.
$$

So the density function is

$$f(x)=n(1-x)^{n-1}.$$

Then

$$\int_0^1 x f(x) dx = n\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{n-1} dx
= n\int_0^1 (1-t) t^{n-1} dt = \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is very helpful.

Comment: Jpi what if $X\sim U(0,\theta)$ ? I am not able to solve the integral when I am trying to find expectation
. @jet Can you answer my question  ?

Comment: @Daman divide the $X_i$'s by $\theta$ first, which is equivalent to multiplying $x$ by $\theta$ in the first display.  Hth

Comment: the change of variable from x to t would require (-dt) and switching the boundary of integral from 1 to 0 - but both cancel out. i.e. $$ n\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{n-1} dx
= n\int_1^0 (1-t) t^{n-1} (-dt) = n\int_0^1 (1-t) t^{n-1} dt.
$$

Answer (score 16):

An short proof *without* the use of the pdf. Suppose $X_i \sim U(0,1)$. Then
\begin{align*}
E[\min(X_i)] &= \int_0^1 P[\min(X_i)>\mu] d\mu \\ 
&= \int_0^1 \prod_i P[X_i>\mu] d\mu \\ 
&= \int_0^1 (1-\mu)^n d\mu\\
&= \int_0^1 \mu^n d\mu\\
&= \dfrac{1}{n+1}
\end{align*}

Comment: How does the 4th integral equals to the 3rd one?

Comment: @Our Change of variables $\mu'=1-\mu$.