# The distribution(or just expectation) of $\min\{U_{1}, U_{2}\}\times \min\{U_{1}, U_{3}\}$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to find the expectation of $\min\{U_{1}, U_{2}\}\times \min\{U_{1}, U_{3}\}$, where $U_{1}, U_{2}, U_{3}$ are independent from $\mathrm{Unif}(0, 1)$, is there any idea?

Comment: I shouldn't forget $E[U_1~|~U_1<U_2]\neq E[U_1]$, I mean its clearer that $E[U_1~|~U_1<U_2,\ldots U_1<U_{100}]\neq E[U_1]$.

Answer (score 1):

I can start you off, use the Law of Total Expectation and this link : [Expectation of Minimum of $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786392/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables) (for the case of two iid uniforms)

\begin{align}
E[\min\{U_1,U_2\}\min\{U_1,U_3\} ]=& \frac{1}{2}\Big(E[\min\{U_1,U_2\}\min\{U_1,U_3\} ~|~ U_1<U_2]
\\
&+E[\min\{U_1,U_2\}\min\{U_1,U_3\} ~|~ U_2<U_1]\Big)
\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\Big(E[U_1\min\{U_1,U_3\}]
\\
&+E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}~|~U_2<U_1]\Big).
\end{align}

Now lets deal with $E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}~|~U_2<U_1]$.

\begin{align}
E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}~|~U_2<U_1]=& E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}~|~U_2<U_1,U_3<U_1]
\\
&+E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}~|~U_2<U_1,U_1<U_3]
\\
=& E[U_2U_3]+E[U_2U_1~|~U_2<U_1]
\end{align}

Now solve $E[U_2U_1~|~U_2<U_1]$ using a double integral.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! But I don't quite understand the second equality you wrote... Should $\frac{1}{2}E[\min\{U_1,U_3\}]$ be $\frac{1}{2}E[U_1\min\{U_1,U_3\}]$?

Comment: @ZhaoZhao that term is $E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\}]$ which because of independence is equal $E[U_2]E[\min\{U_1,U_3\}]$

Comment: How can the conditional term $U_2<U_1$ be dropped in $E[U_2\min\{U_1,U_3\} ~|~ U_2<U_1]$? I know in $E[U_1\min\{U_1,U_3\} ~|~ U_1<U_2]$ the conditional term $U_1<U_2$ can be dropped because $U_2$ is no longer irrelevant.

Comment: I think your right, how about now?

Comment: I think it's correct now, but I suppose an extra factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is needed, and I have added that in your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: not sure where your getting any extra 1/2 from. But your welcome

Comment: The condition cannot be dropped like that. E.g. the conditional distribution of $U_1 \mid U_1 < U_2$ has a different distribution than the original $U_1$. The conditional distribution is like the minimum of the order statistics $U_{(1)}$ with sample size $2$.

Comment: @ZhaoZhao BGM is right, can you un-accept the answer?