# Expectation of minimum of probability density function with $x^{-k}$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value, maxima-minima

Suppose you are sampling from a probability distribution which contains a reciprocal:

$$f(x; \alpha, \lambda) = \begin{cases}\frac{\lambda \alpha^\lambda}{x^{\lambda+1}}~~x\geq \alpha;\\
0 ~~~~~~\text{otherwise};\end{cases}$$

You can't derive the MLE  by minimising the likelihood. Instead you have to use a "trick" and realise that since the function is always decreasing, the likelihood is maximised at $Y = \min(X). $

Is there a trick to work out the expectation $E[Y]$?

I tried to calculate and integrate the PDF using an approach similar to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786392/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables):

$$F_y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 ~~~~~~~~~~~x\lt\alpha;
\\
\frac{\lambda^n \alpha^{n\lambda}}{x^{n(\lambda+1)}}
~~~~x\ge\alpha;
\end{cases}$$

$$f_y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 ~~~~~~~~~~~x\lt\alpha;
\\
\frac{-\lambda^n \alpha^{n\lambda}n(\lambda+1)}
{x^{n(\lambda+1)+1}}
~~~~x\ge\alpha;
\end{cases}$$

Integrating:

$$ E[Y] = \int_\alpha^\infty xf_y(x)dx = 
\frac{\lambda^n \alpha^{1-n}n(\lambda+1)}
{n(\lambda+1)-1}
$$

but I was expecting to get an unbiased estimate of $\alpha$ (or at least close to it).

Comment: $$F_y(x)=1-\frac{\alpha^{n\lambda}}{x^{n\lambda}}=\int_\alpha^xf_y(t)dt\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,f_y(t)=\frac{n\lambda\alpha^{n\lambda}}{t^{n\lambda+1}}$$
$$E[Y]=\int_\alpha^\infty f_y(t)tdt=n\lambda\alpha^{n\lambda}\int_\alpha^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{n\lambda}}=\frac{n\lambda\alpha^{n\lambda}}{n\lambda-1}\alpha^{1-n\lambda}=\frac{n\lambda\alpha}{n\lambda-1}\,\to\,\alpha\,\,\text{at}\,\,n\to\infty$$

Comment: Thank you that solved it! Would you like to put it as an answer and for me to tick it?

Comment: Thank you, this is fine :)