# Posterior of probability density function with $x^{-k}$ and uniform prior

Tags: probability, integration

Suppose you are sampling from a probability distribution which contains a reciprocal:

$$f(x; \alpha, \lambda) = \begin{cases}\frac{\lambda \alpha^\lambda}{x^{\lambda+1}}~~x\geq \alpha;\\
0 ~~~~~~\text{otherwise};\end{cases}$$

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518797/expectation-of-minimum-of-probability-density-function-with-x-k), the likelihood is maximised at $=min(\mathbf X)$.

The prior is assumed to be uniform $U[0,a]  $

The posterior is proportional to the likelihood multiplied by the prior :

$$
\pi(\alpha|\mathbf x) \propto 
\frac{1}{a} 
\frac{\lambda^n \alpha^{n\lambda}}
{\prod x_i^{\lambda+1}}
~~~~~~~~~ 0<\alpha<min(\mathbf X)
$$

The integrand must be equal to 1:

$$
\int_0^{min(\mathbf x)}
\frac{k}{a} 
\frac{\lambda^n \alpha^{n\lambda}}
{\prod x_i^{\lambda+1}} d\alpha= 1
$$

$$
k = \frac{a\prod x_i^{\lambda+1}(n\lambda+1)}{\lambda^nmin(\mathbf x)^{n\lambda+1}}
$$

Plugging this back into the posterior I get:

$$
\pi(\alpha|\mathbf x) = \frac{(n\lambda+1)\alpha^{n\lambda}}{min(\mathbf x)^{n\lambda+1}}
$$

However I was expecting the posterior to be dependent on $a$, as well as $min(\mathbf x)$. Any suggestions on where I have gone wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: So long as $\min(\mathbf x) \lt a$, there is no reason for the posterior to depend on $a$ as $\alpha$ is constrained now by $\min(\mathbf x)$ not by $a$.  You could in fact have  taken an *improper* constant prior density on $[0,\infty)$ and got the same result, with a posterior density supported on $[0,\min(\mathbf x)]$.  
If $\min(\mathbf x) \gt a$, then you need to redo your integral by adjusting the limits, and your posterior density will be supported on $[0,a]$.

Comment: So $\alpha$ is bound by 0 and $min(\mathbf x,a)$ - understood :-)