# Computing Expectation of Summation Involving IID Uniform Random Variables with Conditional Stopping

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value, martingales, order-statistics

Let $ X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be independent and identically distributed random variables, each following a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$. Define the random variable $ S $ as follows:

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{X_i}{2^i},
$$

where $ N $ is the smallest positive integer $ k $ such that $ X_k < X_{k+1} $. If no such $ k $ exists, then $ N = \infty $.
Determine $\mathbb{E}[S]$.

---

I have tried to use the total expectation formula $\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(S |N))$ and I can figure out:

$$
\Pr(N = n) = \Pr(X_1 \ge X_2 \ge \dots \ge X_n, X_n < X_{n + 1}) = \dfrac{n}{(n + 1)!}
$$

But I am having difficulties getting $\mathbb{E}(S |N = n) $ for each $n$

I also wonder if there is any other approaches to this question instead of calculating $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(S |N))$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry I just added some context and how I tried to solve this question.

Comment: $\Bbb E[S\mid N=n]=\dfrac{\Bbb E[S\,\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}}]}{\Bbb P(N=n)}$, isn't it?

Comment: I doubt that the approach of $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(S |N))$ is promising, because knowing $N$ alters the distribution of $X_i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $W_k$ be the indicator variable of the event that $X_1 \ge X_2 \ge \cdots \ge X_{k-1} \ge X_k$. Then the sum can be written as

$$ S= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{X_k W_k}{2^k}$$

Now $E[X_k W_k] = P(W_k=1) E[X_k| W_k = 1]$. And $E[X_k| W_k = 1]$ corresponds to the expectation of the minimum of $k$ uniform random variables. [Which is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786392/expectation-of-minimum-of-n-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables) $1/(k+1)$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I have just worked out this problem thanks to your hints. I'll write a solution here later on.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to leonbloy's hint, I solved this problem, and here is the solution. The result aligns with my simulation results using Python (`0.297443`):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[S] &= \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^N \dfrac{X_i}{2^i}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{X_i \mathbf{1}[i \le N]}{2^i}] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^i}\mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbf{1}[N\ge i]] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^i}(\Pr(N\ge i) \mathbb{E}[X_i | N\ge i] + \Pr(N < i)\cdot 0) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^i}\Pr(N\ge i) \mathbb{E}[X_i | N\ge i]
\end{aligned}
$$

We have

$$
\Pr(N \ge i) = \Pr(X_1 \ge X_2\ge \dots \ge X_i) = \dfrac{1}{i!}
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i|N\ge i] = \mathbb{E}[X_i|X_1 \ge X_2\ge \dots \ge X_i] = \dfrac{1}{i+1}
$$

So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[S] &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^i} \dfrac{1}{i!} \dfrac{1}{i+1} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{(1/2)^i}{(i + 1)!} \\
&= 2\sum_{i=2}^\infty \dfrac{(1/2)^i}{i!} \\
&= 2 (e^{1/2} - 1 - 1/2) \\
&= 2 e^{1/2} - 3
\end{aligned}
$$