# Expectation of $max\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ when $X \sim U[0,\lambda]$

Tags: integration, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,\lambda]$. Let $\{x_i\}$ be a random sample of size $n$ from the population.

Is there any way to compute $E[max\{x_1,...,x_n\}]$ with this information?

Comment: Hint: Compute the cdf for $max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ using the fact that $max\{X_1,...,X_n\} \leq \alpha \iff X_1 \leq \alpha$ and $...$ and $X_n \leq \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks. Computed the cdf and pdf. Then, how do I compute the integral for the expected value?

Comment: Have you tried to compute the integral?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M:=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. Then for $x\in(0,\lambda)$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(M\le x)=(\mathsf{P}(X\le x))^n=(x/\lambda)^n,
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{E}M=\int_0^{\infty}\mathsf{P}(M> x)\,dx=\int_0^{\lambda}1-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^n\,dx=\lambda\times \frac{ n}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Where does the expression for $ E(M)$ come from (the first equality)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63756/tail-sum-for-expectation