# When is the expectation of the maximum bounded

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

Let $\epsilon\equiv(\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_J)$ be a random vector. Let $F$ be the probability distribution of $\epsilon$.

**Assumption 1:** $F$ has full support on $\mathbb{R}^J$.

**Assumption 2:** $F$ has marginals that are identical and symmetric around zero.

Take a vector of reals $U\equiv (U_1,\dots, U_J)\in [a,b]^J$ with $|a|<\infty, |b|< \infty$.

Consider the quantity
$$
\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{X^*})
$$
where
$$
X^*\equiv argmax_{j\in \{1,\dots,J\}}\Big(U_j+ \epsilon_{j}\Big)
$$

Note that under Assumption 1, $X^*$ is unique with probability 1. Assumption 1 wil be maintained throughout.

**Claim 0**: Under Assumptions 1 and 2 (and without further assumptions on $F$), $|\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{X^*})|$ is not bounded away from $\infty$  (i.e., it might be equal to $\infty$).

---

**QUESTION:** I want to show Claim 0.    Could you help?

---

**SUB-QUESTION:** Suppose we replace Assumption 2 with Assumption 3.

**Assumption 3:** $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_J$ are mutually independent and identically distributed. In particular, for $j=1,...,J$,  $\epsilon_j$ has a Gumbel distribution with scale 1 and location 0.

Under Assumption  3 (which   implies also Assumption 1), we know that $
|\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{X^*})|<\infty$.

Therefore, I wonder which assumption is actually needed to ensure that $|\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{X^*})|<\infty$ (while maintaining the full support condition).
My prior is that we need some restrictions on the shape  of $F$ in the tails. Is this correct? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose (for symplicity) that $\mathsf{P}(U_i+\epsilon_i=U_j+\epsilon_j)=0$ for any $i\ne j$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}|\epsilon_{X^*}|&=\sum_{j=1}^J \mathsf{E}[|\epsilon_j|1\{X^*=j\}] \\
&\le J\max_{1\le j\le J}\mathsf{E}|\epsilon_j|. 
\end{align}
Therefore, $\mathsf{E}|\epsilon_{X^*}|<\infty$ as long as each $\epsilon_j$ is integrable. On the other hand, if $\mathsf{E}\min_{1\le j\le J}|\epsilon_j|=\infty$, then
$$
\mathsf{E}|\epsilon_{X^*}|\ge \mathsf{E}\min_{1\le j\le J}|\epsilon_j|=\infty.
$$

Comment: @TEX Probably the easiest example is the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). As for the second question, I gave a trivial sufficient condition. I think, this can be further strengthened, e.g, $\mathsf{E}\varepsilon_{X*}^+=\infty$ if $\mathsf{E}\varepsilon_j^{+}=\infty$ for some $j$.

Comment: @TEX It is the positive part of $\epsilon_j$ or $\max\{\epsilon_j,0\}$. You're right it is not "iff".

Comment: @TEX Sure. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63756/tail-sum-for-expectation

Comment: I think I'm  confused.  You showed  (1): 
 $E(|\epsilon_{X^*}|)\leq J\max_j \mathbb{E}|\epsilon_j|$; hence, if $\epsilon_j$ is integrable, then $|E(\epsilon_{X^*})| \leq E(|\epsilon_{X^*}|)\leq J\max_j \mathbb{E}|\epsilon_j|<\infty$, where the first inequality follows from Jensen's inequality (recall that I'm interested in $|E(\epsilon_{X^*})|$ ultimately.

Comment: You also showed (2): $E(|\epsilon_{X^*}|)\geq   \mathbb{E} \min_j |\epsilon_j|$; hence,  if $\mathbb{E} \min_j |\epsilon_j|=\infty$, then $E(|\epsilon_{X^*}|)\geq \infty$;  I'm not sure how to use this to say that $|E(\epsilon_{X^*})|$ can be unbounded.

Comment: Finally, in the comments you  mentioned (3): if $E(\epsilon^+_j)=\infty$ for some $j$, then $E(|\epsilon^+_{X^*}|)=\infty$; hence, by Jensen's inequality, $|E(\epsilon^+_{X^*})|=\infty$; again, I'm not sure how to use this to say something about $|E(\epsilon_{X^*})|$.

Comment: @TEX Note that $\mathsf{E} \epsilon_{X^*}$ may not be defined! That's why I used $\mathsf{E}|\epsilon_{X^*}|$ instead.

Comment: OK thanks, but I don't know how to use the relations you show to answer my original question

Answer (score 0):

Question 0 very much depends on the distribution $F$. For example, if $F$ were to be multivariate normal with mean vector 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then
\begin{align*}
|\mathbb{E} \epsilon_{X^*}| \le \sum_{j=1}^{J}\mathbb{E}|\epsilon_{j}| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\text{trace}(\Sigma) < \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for more generic conditions than referring to a specific parametric family.

Answer (score 0):

simplest example that shows this is: let's have $X \sim N(0, 1)$ (whatever with support $R$ with bounded mean) and for $k \in \mathbb{R} $, $Y$ with distribution $F_{N(k, 0.01)}/2 + F_{N(-k, 0.01)}/2$ to have continuous distribution and behavior close to $P(Y=k)=P(Y=-k)=0.5$, now $\epsilon=(X,Y)$ it's easy to see that $lim_{k \to \infty} E[\epsilon_{X^*}] \to \infty$, in general we can have this value arbitrary big, if we allowed to have $k=\infty$ then expected value can be $\infty$

Comment: Thanks, but each marginal is continuous in my setting.

Comment: @TEX please take a look on changes